# MacBook Pro won't recognise Sandisk 64GB Mini SD card

Tags: macbook-pro, software-update, sd-card

I bought a 64GB Sandisk for my GoPro Hero 3+ and it works fine.

However, when I either plug in my GoPro directly via a USB cable or try to access the drive by using an SD-card adapter, all that comes up is

> The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer.

The options presented are `Initialise`, `Ignore` and `Eject`. When I select `Initialise` it comes up with a program I have never used or seen before.

I am not very good with computers so any help is great! I have recently had my laptop updated but I am not sure which update it has.

(My laptop reads other cards and this card works on a Windows computer.)

Answer (score 2):

The HERO3+ camera uses the [exFAT file system format](http://gopro.com/support/articles/exfat-computer-compatibility) and it should be readable on your Mac if it uses Mac OS X from Snow Leopard on up. The link above notes that if you are having difficulty using a 64GB card, that you can use a 32GB or smaller card and format it with the old FAT32 standard.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have had a look at the link above and my Mac has Mavericks so i don't think it is compatible. Any suggestions in how i can make it work?

Comment: Problem sovled, very happy.

Comment: Please mark my answer as the solution, please, if the problem has been solved.